# Showing Calender Years only in input field with bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using Bootstrap datetimepicker (can see [here](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/))

I have bunch of input fields attached with this datetimepicker, these are working fine to show only dates,time and datetime as well.

I wana to show only the "years" in the input field and datetimepicker popup as well, user can only navigate years list and select an year to be showing in the input field.

Is there any way to achieve this thing using this plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have it by simply defining the datetimepicker as below

```
$('Your selector').datetimepicker({
    format      :   "YYYY",
    viewMode    :   "years", 
});
```

Please find below link to JSFiddle Working demo

https://jsfiddle.net/2n4pnrf1/

Comment: Yeah, i am already this code snippet, Although this is initially displaying the years-view and later ask user to select month, day etc.
But i want to show and select only year(s) and input field should only contain the selected-year only not whole date/time

Comment: Hi Naeem i have added the working demo link, have a look at it. Its working as you needed.

Comment: Hi Parkash, 
I was using previous versions of the moment.js and datetimepicker.js and i think the issue is fixed in later versions.
I just updated my plugins versions and functionality is working as expected now.
Got help from your jsfiddle link.
Thanks